# text align with different character count

Tags: android, android-layout

I am really really sorry about my poor English

Here is what I made.

[image]

with

```
  <LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <TextView android:id="@+id/txtTImeRemain"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dip"
    android:textColor="#ff000000"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
    />
  <TextView android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:textColor="#ff000000"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

My question is.

I want to align the left most words to being center of their row. regardless how many character they have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `TableLayout`, then you can set the layout_gravity for the different parts of the table row.

Comment: my original question is not 'row' , it was 'column'  but I solved it with TableLayout and layout_gravity.  thank you!